# How to adjust field names in Nancy model bindings?

Tags: .net, nancy

In a web application I use Nancy for creating a REST service. Unfortunately, in HTML our field names are lowercase (`firstName`), but the appropriate properties in .NET are uppercase (`FirstName`). Moreover, we have some fields that don't map 1:1, such as `id` that shall become `TicketId` in .NET.

Now I have two question on this:

1. Is Nancy case-sensitive or case-insensitive when it comes to field names?
2. Does Nancy provide some sort of mapping for field names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for this is there, but it's not as fully featured as I'd like.

If you take a look at the [IFieldNameConverter](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/IFieldNameConverter.cs) interface (it's default implementation is [DefaultFieldNameConverter](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/DefaultFieldNameConverter.cs)), that's what handles converting field names for things like casing.

For more complicated mappings you'd have to implement an [ITypeConverter](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/ITypeConverter.cs), you could just "wrap" the [default converter(s)](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/DefaultConverters) - depending on your data - and alter the input before calling the default one.

Comment: After implementing a custom converter, how do I setup Nancy to use it?