# Nancy FX capitalizes keys in dictionaries on model binding

Tags: c#, json, model-binding, nancy

I'm trying to post a JSON to NancyFx. The JSON is the following:

```
{  
   "prop1": 1,
   "entries":{  
      "Entry1": 1,
      "entry2": 2
   }
}
```

On server side I created a corresponding model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

`entries` field in JSON has a dynamic structure, and because of that `IDictionary<string, object>` is used in the model.

And then I bind the model:

```
this.Bind<Model>();
```

Model is created successfully but problem is that in `Entries` dictionary both keys are in capital case. For me case is very important and I expect second key to be ***e***ntry2, not ***E***ntry2.

I also tried to use `JavaScriptConverter` and `JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter` but in `Deserialize` method I get already capitalized data.

Any ideas oh how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe down to this https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/DefaultFieldNameConverter.cs if so is good news as you can create your own.

Comment: Some more info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18781862/360211

Comment: @weston do you now how to register your custom `FieldNameConverter`? I tried it with creating my own `Bootstrapper` and registering my version with IoC, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure. I would have a look at the Nancy code to see how the default one is registered.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was solved by configuring `JavascriptSerializer` to retain casing.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a clean way to do this, but here's the hack I'm using for now.

```
    public class Model
    {
        public IDictionary<string, object> Entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {

        public bool CanBind(Type modelType)
        {
            return modelType == typeof(Model);
        }

        public object Bind(NancyContext context, Type modelType, object instance, BindingConfig configuration, params string[] blackList)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
            {
                return (new JavaScriptSerializer() { RetainCasing = true }).Deserialize<Model>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

Nancy will pick up this binder at runtime, no need to explicitly register anything.

This solution is not ideal because it ignores some Nancy features like blacklists and possibly other binding configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to set JsonSettings from Bootstrapper

```
public class MyBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    public MyBootstrapper () : base()
    {
        JsonSettings.RetainCasing = true;
    }
}
```

Implementing IModelBinder works, but it messes up other default binding settings.